# Rename [watch-os-...] tags to [watchos-...]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Currently, the following three tags exist and pertain to the operating system running on Apple Watches:

- [`watch-os`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watch-os/info)
- [`watch-os-2`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watch-os-2/info)
- [`watch-os-2-beta3`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watch-os-2-beta3/info)

However, this naming is inconsistent with other tags for Apple platforms. For example:

- "iOS" is mapped to [`ios`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/info), [`ios7`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios7/info), [`ios-simulator`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios-simulator/info), etc.
- "tvOS" is mapped to [`tvos`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tvos/info)
- "OS X" is mapped to [`osx`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osx/info)

Renaming the watchOS related tags to `watchos`, `watchos2`, etc. would fix this. Please discuss; if most are in agreement then please additionally consider this post a request for a mod to perform the rename.

Comment: `watchos` sounds like `nachos`

Comment: @miva2 all the more reason to rename? ;)

Comment: It seems inevitable that Apple's going to rebrand OS X as macOS (or maybe OSx) in the near future. I know we shouldn't make changes based on a prediction like that, but I think it's a reason to give the current "OS X" less weight compared to the other platforms when choosing a tag convention.

Comment: @JeremyBanks true, although all Apple platform tags highlighted above are consistent _except_ watchOS anyway :)

Comment: In some OS 9 material (notably the system load screen), it was written "MacOS" (the breakfast cereal to watchOS's late-night snack). @JeremyBanks